# Using a loop to create 10 similar fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, iteration

I'm a beginner on my first project.   If I have 10 similar fields, is there a way to create them dry so they would still work with validations?  I would also like to put the loop number in the attribute name, because the attributes are named field_name_1 through to field_name_10, for example.

```
<% 10.times do |asdf| %>
    <%= f.input :field_name_(asdf + 1), etc %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please share schema.

Comment: t.string "field_name_1", t.string "field_name_2", t.string "field_name_3", t.string "field_name_4", t.string "field_name_5", t.string "field_name_6", t.string "field_name_7", t.string "field_name_8", t.string "field_name_9", t.string "field_name_10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work !!!

```
<% (1..10).each do |n| %> 
<%= f.input ("field_name_"+n.to_s).to_sym, etc %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!   Will that work together with the error if the form has to reset due to failed validation?

Comment: Yes. please check it and let me know if anything goes wrong...

Comment: I had to add (1..10).each, but otherwise worked great.   I won't be able to test validation errors until later, but I'll take your word on it, thanks!

Comment: Also nice is your solution but like this: `@things.each_with_index do |thing, i|` then `("field_name_+i.to_s)`.